# Simple html dom not fetching or loading the full html file despite meeting the memory limits

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm running a scraper on localhost and am having trouble scraping a 2.50MB html file that's stored on a website directory on my computer.

Right now I have

- 36MB memory is allocated
- Memory usage of 18.93MB to fetch test.html
- The test.html file being scraped is 2.50MB

---

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once 'simplehtmldom-2rc2/HtmlWeb.php';
use simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb;
$doc = new HtmlWeb();
$html = $doc->load('http://localhost/onetab/test.html');
```

I have a file called `test.html` that when I add 1 more character to it, my scraper fails to fetch the file.

Given the memory limit and memory usage stated above, how can adding one extra character to `test.html` cause the `->load` function to fail so `$html` is blank (or null)?

I'm using [Simple HTML Dom version 2 RC2](https://github.com/simplehtmldom/simplehtmldom).

Using the following lines does not help.

```
set_time_limit(0); // 0 is infinite, or it could be 5000
ini_set('max_input_time', 5000 );
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000 );
ini_set('max_input_vars', 5000 );
ini_set('max_input_nesting_level', 5000 );
```

[image: problems with simple html dom scraper v2rc2]

Comment: please tell us what the error message(s) are. (You have enabled error reporting) . On the other hand, what do you mean by "add one more character to it" ?

Comment: I'm just adding one numerical digit using the keyboard. The file has UTF-8 encoding. There is no error, no error appears. Here's a video illustrating this. https://i.imgur.com/XcguWDN.gif

Comment: Did you (1) click "save" after inserting the extra character and (2) quit the editor before you re-run the PHP script ?

Comment: Yes to both of them.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you add anything else but a digit? Does the same error happen if you add a character somewhere else in the document?

Comment: Yes it happens if I add an alphabetical character somewhere else in the `test.html` document.

Comment: I've solved the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Simple HTML DOM version 2 RC2 library there is a `constants.php` file with some settings to change. In it the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` constant (a type of variable) has to be changed.

To make it accept a 9MB file I set the value to `1024 * 1024 * 9`. You could just change the value to be the number or numerical sum you want, or you might even want to make it a variable like

```
$chosenvalue = 1024 * 1024 * 9; //9mb file (bytes --> kilobytes --> megabytes)
```

These instructions are mentioned in the `manual/api/constants.md` file. But because the library is still a release candidate while waiting for a final stable  version release, the documentation is not written fully in a clear manner as an offline file. You can read [the relevant documentation web page](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/constants/) online.